# Silverlight/XAML Convert text to upper case

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Im working on a design in Blend 4 for Silverlight, however much of my text in the design needs to be in UPPERCASE.

It appears that Blend and XAML dont support this, I was wondering if its possible to do it in CSharp?

Basically I'd like to be able to style certain parts of text as UPPERCASE, can anyone suggest any code that might do this. Perhaps a text convertor of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using [a converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) in your binding declaration

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the caps-lock key on your kayboard ;) JK

You could easily create a Converter for this, but that would mean a fair amount of effort in binding all text fields to use a converter. Nothing dramatic, just a bit of overhead.